# Can a user permanently amend an HTML file through the browser?

Tags: javascript, html

For example- could the user change the actual code of the HTML from the web browser using a JavaScript prompt?

If I had the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>var person = prompt("Please enter your name");</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This should be user amendable</p>
<p>This shouldn't</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't mean to store the variable `person` temporarily, but actually change the HTML code and replace it with the value of the variable?

Comment: No, the only way they can change the HTML is by saving it on their PC and editing it there.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No I didn't think so. There's nothing I'm really trying to accomplish with this, it was more curiosity than anything else. Thanks for all of your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as such. Alternatives include:

- You could take the changes and send them to a server using XMLHttpRequest. The server could respond by storing them and sending the new version to anyone who requested it in future.
- You could store the changes in local storage / a cookie / etc, and include some JavaScript in the page that looks for that data and updates the page as soon as it loads.
- A browser plugin could be written that could store modifications to be made to a given URL.

Answer (score 0):

If your prompt submits the data to a form handler written in PHP or some other server side application, it can access the file system in a way in which you could permanently edit the content, however you should avoid doing this for security purposes without creating a much more robust system in which to check that the information entered into the prompt is not malicious.  In short, this is best left to CMS (Content Management System), which are more likely to save the actual "content" of your website as part of a database structure.